# iOS design pattern to upload items to web while showing progress in a TableView

Tags: ios, cocoa, design-patterns, nsoperation

I am trying to remove some UI code dependency from my upload methods to get a better understanding of MVC paradigms.

I want to design a way to visualize upload progress inside a UITableView, with individual cells being designated to show corresponding NSOperation subclasses. My NSOperation subclass has been hacked to support a delegate callback pattern (ie non-concurrent/mainThread only). The NSOperation looks like this:

```
@class MyUploadOp;
@protocol MyUploadDelegate;
-(void)uploadOp:(MyUploadOp *)uploadOp madeProgress:(CGFloat)progress;
-(void)uploadOp:(MyUploadOp *)uploadOp didUploadLocalFile:(LocalFileObject *)localFile;
@end

@interface MyUploadOp : NSOperation <DBRestClientDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) LocalFileObject *myLocalFile;
-(id)initWithLocalFile:(LocalFileObject *)localFile;
@end
```

As you can see, I am using the Dropbox SDK for iOS. This NSOperation subclass uploads a local file to Dropbox. I receive the necessary Dropbox delegate methods inside the NSOperation class and then forward them onward to the class that is responsible for setting up and keeping track of the upload.

What I would like to do, is set up a new UITableViewController, and some custom UITableViewCells. I don't need help with this part, yadda yadda. What I need help with is:

- Keeping track of NSOperations that may get set up
- Assigning each NSOperation to a UITableViewCell
- Who should be the delegate of my NSOperation to receive these messages?
- Should I instead set properties on my Operation, like "progress" and use KeyValue Observing?
- If this is the case, what object should do the observing? The cell or the viewController?
- What happens when the NSOperation finishes and disappears from the queue, I need to keep a record around to make sure the table stays populated.
- Updating the UIProgressBars in my cells on every delegate method call
- Keeping items in the table upon NSOperation completion

My current code is currently *working*, but I don't have any table stuff implemented yet. I can't figure out the best way to keep track of these items. Maybe I need to come up with an NSObject subclass that holds a reference the the Operation, and fill my table with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Keeping track of NSOperations that may get set up

Add a property to the operation so you can set an identifier. Then, when the delegate methods are called you can read the identifier and translate it to an index path. In your table view controller class, keep an array of the identifiers (the index in the array is the row number it's displayed at).

> Assigning each NSOperation to a UITableViewCell

As just described.

> Who should be the delegate of my NSOperation to receive these messages?

The table view controller.

> Should I instead set properties on my Operation, like "progress" and use KeyValue Observing?

No, but you should probably cache the progress value in an array in the table view controller so if the cells are scrolled off screen you can update them when they are scrolled back on screen (without having to go and find the operation and query it).

> What happens when the NSOperation finishes and disappears from the queue, I need to keep a record around to make sure the table stays populated.

That's fine, just don't remove the identifier from your array.

> Updating the UIProgressBars in my cells on every delegate method call

Use the contents of the arrays stored in your table view controller. One for the identifiers and one for the progress value. Both arrays should always have the same number of items in them.

Comment: Alright, since each Operation includes a reference to a LocalFileObject, I guess the "identifier" could be a string based on the file path. Clarification: what's the best way to translate to an indexPath, other than enumerating the data source and counting up until a match is found (between identifiers)

Comment: The index path row is the index of the item in the array. You can call `indexOfObject` to get the appropriate row number when you receive a progress update.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It works beautifully. I didn't assign an NSOperation to a cell, I mapped the Queue contents to a custom array, with NSDictionary objects to represent the operations. Doing it this way makes for easy serialization to keep track of past uploads.